# Android : How to Store the Value for a Variable in Strings.xml through coding

Tags: java, android, xml

Requirement : I need to store the values of the User Id and Password as string values in String.xml, which are indeed taken by the user.

Problem : As far as i have seen the solutions are to use Shared Preferences. Though i use Shared Preferences , the values don't get stored in String.xml

Here, is my Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

<string name="app_name">Sp</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="id" ></string>  <!-- fill in this value from java code, how ? -->
<string name="pwd"></string>  <!-- fill in this value from java code, how ? -->

 </resources>
```

layout page : activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/text"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
     android:ems="10"
     android:text="id" >

     <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
     android:text="Send" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
     android:text="id" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

EdText.java

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;


public class EdText extends Activity {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);


    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            String s1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString().trim();

          //Saving your strings
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context).edit();
        editor.putString("s1", s1.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();     



    //retrieving your strings from preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s12 = prefs.getString("s12", ""); //empty string is the default value


     }

    });
} }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: `Strings.xml` cannot be changed at runtime by the app. Save to SharedPreferences/Database and read from there. I don't know how you got the idea that `SharedPreferences` saves to `Strings.xml`.

Comment: That's impossible it is `static` and "read-only"

Comment: strings.xml is used by the compiler to create your .apk file. An Android device does not know anything about this file.

Comment: u also save data in file , static variable or DB...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where you get that idea but it is static and thus cannot be changed on run time.

You could however make a work around here

First create a class and add a Public Static String for that

e.g

```
public class StringGen {

public static String username
    public static String password
}
```

Set your data perhaps log in

```
StringGen.username = *yourString*
```

And just call it on your app (activities , etc)

```
String myUsername = StringGen.username
```

Cheers